# lambda vs function object

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

The following code snippet doesn't compile because of the absence of copy ctor.

```
template <typename Func>
void print(Func f) {
    f();
}

struct abc {
    abc() = default;
    abc(const abc&) = delete;
    abc& operator=(const abc&) = delete;

    void operator()() {
        std::cout << "f" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    abc s;

    print(s);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Why does the following compile? I thought lambda doesn't have copy ctor either.

```
template <typename Func>
void print(Func f) {
    f();
}

int main() {
    auto f = []() {
        std::cout << "f" << std::endl;
    };

    print(f);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I am using  g++ -std=c++11.

Comment: *"I thought lambda doesn't have copy ctor either"* - That's not true in general. Take a look at the constructors of the closure type. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: See here different rules depending on capture vs no-capture and before/after C++20  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the following compile?

Beacuse the lambda is copy-constructible.

> I thought lambda doesn't have copy ctor either.

You thought wrong. Lambda closures are copy-constructible as long as they have no non-copyable value-captures.